# Mantener el valor del Sppiner

Tags: base-de-datos, spinner

Buenas tardes tengo un Spinner que obtento desde la base de datos mysql pero quiero mantener cmo la primera opcion el valor que el trae de la base de datos como logro eso aca dejo el codigo.....

```
private void CrearSpinnerUsuarios(JSONArray obj) {
    try {
        List<String> contes = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray lista = obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = lista.getJSONObject(i);
            String conte = json_data.getString("Id");

            contes.add(conte);
        }


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, contes);
        spinner_usuarios = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_usuario);
        spinner_usuarios.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error de cargando lista" + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } finally {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

asumiendo que tu spinner es "contes" te dejo el siguiente código para probar.

```
 contes.setSelection(obtenerPosicionItem(contes, inicializarItem));

//Método para obtener la posición de un ítem del spinner
    public static int obtenerPosicionItem(Spinner spinner, String seleccionado) {
        //Creamos la variable posicion y lo inicializamos en 0
        int posicion = 0;
        //Recorre el spinner en busca del ítem que coincida con el parametro `String seleccionado`
        //que lo pasaremos posteriormente
        for (int i = 0; i < spinner.getCount(); i++) {
            //Almacena la posición del ítem que coincida con la búsqueda
            if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(seleccionado)) {
                posicion = i;
            }
        }
        //Devuelve un valor entero (si encontró una coincidencia devuelve la
        // posición 0 o N, de lo contrario devuelve 0 = posición inicial)
        return posicion;
    }
```

Ante cualquier duda, consulta!